# thread-safety issues managing connections objects inside a TCP server

Tags: c++, sockets, server, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm coding  a simple client-server application using TCP. I'm using Winsock, but I'm limiting myself to the BSD socket API (since I want the code to run on Linux as well).
The application should run a server and accept incoming client connections, receive and send messages, and gracefully handle client disconnections. The approach I use is this:

(disclaimer: I know it might not be the best one, and that there are a bunch of more efficient techniques, but I'm just starting with network programming)

A connection object (that represents the actual endpoint of the connection and contains a socket object) has a queue of outgoing messages, and a reference to a queue of incoming messages (actual incoming messages queues are inside the clients and the server object, and are passed on construction):

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_H
#define CONNECTION_H

#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include "ThreadsafeQueue.h"
#include "Message.h"
#include "debug.h"

template <typename T>
class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection<T>>
{
public:
    enum class Owner { CLIENT, SERVER };
private:
    using std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>::shared_from_this;
public:
    Connection(Owner owner, uint32_t id, SOCKET socket, ThreadsafeQueue<OwnedMessage<T>> &inMessageQueue);
    ~Connection();

    void Send(const Message<T> &message);  
    void Close();
    bool IsOpen() const { return mIsOpen; }

    uint32_t GetId() const { return mId; }
private:
    const Owner mOwner;
    uint32_t mId;
    SOCKET mSocket;
    bool mIsOpen;

    ThreadsafeQueue<Message<T>> mOutMessageQueue;
    ThreadsafeQueue<OwnedMessage<T>> &mInMessageQueue;

    std::thread mSendThread;
    std::thread mReceiveThread;

    void Send_();
    void Receive_();
};

template <typename T>
Connection<T>::Connection(Owner owner, uint32_t id, SOCKET socket, ThreadsafeQueue<OwnedMessage<T>> &inMessageQueue) : mOwner(owner), mId(id), mSocket(socket), mInMessageQueue(inMessageQueue)
{
    unsigned long socketMode = 1U;
    if (ioctlsocket(socket, FIONBIO, &socketMode) != 0)  // set non blocking socket
        Error("error setting socket i/o mode");

    mIsOpen = true;
    mSendThread = std::thread(&Connection<T>::Send_, this);
    mReceiveThread = std::thread(&Connection<T>::Receive_, this);
}

template <typename T>
Connection<T>::~Connection()
{
    Close();
}

template <typename T>
void Connection<T>::Send(const Message<T> &message)
{
    mOutMessageQueue.EnQueue(message);
}

template <typename T>
void Connection<T>::Close()
{
    if (mIsOpen)
        mIsOpen = false;

    if (mSendThread.joinable())
        mSendThread.join();

    if (mReceiveThread.joinable())
        mReceiveThread.join();

    closesocket(mSocket);
}

template <typename T>
void Connection<T>::Send_()
{
    //DbgPrint("send thread start");

    while (mIsOpen)
    {
        // get from outgoing queue and send 
        if (!mOutMessageQueue.Empty())
        {
            Message<T> outMessage = mOutMessageQueue.Front();
            mOutMessageQueue.DeQueue();

            int sendFlags = 0;
            int totalBytesSent = 0;

            while (totalBytesSent < sizeof(Message<T>::Header))
            {
                int bytesSent = send(mSocket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&outMessage.mHeader) + totalBytesSent, sizeof(Message<T>::Header) - totalBytesSent, sendFlags);
                totalBytesSent += bytesSent;

                if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    Error("error sending message");
            }   

            totalBytesSent = 0;
            while (totalBytesSent < outMessage.mBody.Size())
            {
                int bytesSent = send(mSocket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(outMessage.mBody.Data()) + totalBytesSent, outMessage.mBody.Size() - totalBytesSent, sendFlags);
                totalBytesSent += bytesSent;

                if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    Error("error sending message");
            }
        }
    }

    //DbgPrint("send thread end");
}

template <typename T>
void Connection<T>::Receive_()
{
    //DbgPrint("receive thread start");

    static bool skip = false;  // used in non blocking mode

    while (mIsOpen)
    {
        skip = false;

        Message<T> inMessage;

        int recvFlags = 0;
        int totalBytesReceived = 0;

        while (totalBytesReceived < sizeof(Message<T>::Header))  // receive message header
        {
            int bytesReceived = recv(mSocket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&inMessage.mHeader) + totalBytesReceived, sizeof(Message<T>::Header) - totalBytesReceived, recvFlags);

            if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                skip = true;
                break;
            }

            if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
                Error("error receiving message");
            else if (bytesReceived == 0)  // other side closed connection
            {
                mIsOpen = false;
                skip = true;
                break;
            }

            totalBytesReceived += bytesReceived;
        }

        if (skip)
            continue;

        inMessage.mBody.Resize(inMessage.mHeader.mSize);

        totalBytesReceived = 0;
        while (totalBytesReceived < inMessage.mBody.Size())  // receive message body
        {
            int bytesReceived = recv(mSocket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(inMessage.mBody.Data()) + totalBytesReceived, inMessage.mBody.Size() - totalBytesReceived, recvFlags);

            if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                continue;

            totalBytesReceived += bytesReceived;

            if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
                Error("error receiving message");
            else if (bytesReceived == 0)  // other side closed connection
            {
                mIsOpen = false;
                skip = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (skip)
            continue;

        if (mOwner == Owner::SERVER)
            mInMessageQueue.EnQueue(OwnedMessage<T>(shared_from_this(), inMessage));  // put received message into incoming queue   
        else
            mInMessageQueue.EnQueue(OwnedMessage<T>(nullptr, inMessage));
    }                                                                      

    //DbgPrint("receive thread start");
}

#endif  // CONNECTION_H
```

A client has one Connection objects, the server has many of them in a container. Server runs and accept clients, spawns a Connection and put it into a container. Each connection runs in two threads (one to send and the other to receive, since my sockets are non-blocking it is redundant, I'll address the issue in the future). The connected client stores its own connection as well. The Send_ () and Receive_() threads take care of transferring messages in and out of the message queues (which are brutally thread-safe by synchronizing every operation on a std::mutex, not the best design I know).

The server runs two threads: one to keep listening to incoming clients, the other to "garbage-collect" the closed connections: a server-side Connection can detect if a client closed its connection by reading 0 from recv(), and signals that to the server by setting mIsOpen to false. The CloseSocket thread runs and cleans up the connections (calling the OnClientDisconnect hook):

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include "Vector.h"
#include "Connection.h"
#include "ThreadsafeQueue.h"
#include "Message.h"
#include "debug.h"

template <typename T>
class Server
{
protected:
    using ConnectionPtr = std::shared_ptr<Connection<T>>;
public:
    Server(uint16_t port);
    ~Server();

    void Start();
    void Stop();
    void Send(ConnectionPtr connection, const Message<T> &message) const;
    void SendAll(const Message<T> &message, ConnectionPtr ignore = nullptr) const;
    void Disconnect(ConnectionPtr connection);

    bool Available() const { return !mInMessageQueue.Empty(); }
    void ProcessMessage();
protected:
    virtual void OnClientConnect(ConnectionPtr connection) = 0;
    virtual void OnClientDisconnect(ConnectionPtr connection) = 0;
    virtual void OnMessage(ConnectionPtr sender, Message<T> &message) = 0;
private:
    Vector<ConnectionPtr> mConnections;
    ThreadsafeQueue<OwnedMessage<T>> mInMessageQueue;
    
    SOCKET mListenSocket;
    std::thread mListenThread;
    void Listen();

    std::thread mSocketRemoveThread;
    void RemoveConnections();

    std::string mHost;
    uint16_t mPort;
    static const uint8_t sMaxNumConnections = 10;
    bool mIsRunning;
};

template <typename T>
Server<T>::Server(uint16_t port) :mListenSocket(INVALID_SOCKET), mIsRunning(false)
{
    WSAData wsa;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);

    addrinfo hints, *address;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    //hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if (getaddrinfo(nullptr, std::to_string(port).c_str(), &hints, &address) != 0)
        Error("cannot get server address");

    char stringBuf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    if (address->ai_family == AF_INET)
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in *>(address->ai_addr)->sin_addr, stringBuf, sizeof stringBuf);
    else  // address->ai_family == AF_INET6
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6 *>(address->ai_addr)->sin6_addr, stringBuf, sizeof stringBuf);

    mHost = stringBuf;

    mPort = ntohs(address->ai_family == AF_INET ? reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in *>(address->ai_addr)->sin_port : reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6 *>(address->ai_addr)->sin6_port);

    if ((mListenSocket = socket(address->ai_family, address->ai_socktype, address->ai_protocol)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        Error("cannot create server socket");

    if (bind(mListenSocket, address->ai_addr, address->ai_addrlen) != 0)  
        Error("cannot bind server socket");
}

template <typename T>
Server<T>::~Server()
{
    if (mIsRunning)
        closesocket(mListenSocket);

    WSACleanup();
}

template <typename T>
void Server<T>::Start()
{
    if (mIsRunning)  // TODO: error check
        return;

    mIsRunning = true;

    PRINTLN("server running");

    mListenThread = std::thread(&Server::Listen, this);   // start thread that accepts new connections   
    mSocketRemoveThread = std::thread(&Server::RemoveConnections, this);
}
template <typename T>
void Server<T>::Stop()
{
    for (std::unique_ptr<Connection<T>> &connection : mConnections)
        connection->Close();
}

template <typename T>
void Server<T>::Listen()
{
    if (listen(mListenSocket, sMaxNumConnections) != 0)
        Error("listen error");

    PRINT("server listening @ ");
    PRINT(mHost);
    PRINT(" on port ");
    PRINTLN(std::to_string(mPort));

    static uint32_t connectionId = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        sockaddr_storage clientAddress;
        int clientAddressLength = sizeof(sockaddr_storage);
        SOCKET clientSocket = accept(mListenSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&clientAddress), &clientAddressLength);    // accept connections (blocking)

        if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            Error("cannot create client socket");

        mConnections.EmplaceLast(new Connection<T>(Connection<T>::Owner::SERVER, connectionId++, clientSocket, mInMessageQueue));    // create new connection to client (receive/send threads)
        OnClientConnect(mConnections.Last());                                                          // callback called on new connections

        char stringBuf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        if (clientAddress.ss_family == AF_INET)
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in *>(&clientAddress)->sin_addr, stringBuf, sizeof stringBuf);
        else  // clientAddress.ss_family == AF_INET6
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6 *>(&clientAddress)->sin6_addr, stringBuf, sizeof stringBuf);

        PRINT("accepted connection from "); 
        PRINT(stringBuf);
        PRINT(" on port ");
        PRINTLN(clientAddress.ss_family == AF_INET ? std::to_string(ntohs(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in *>(&clientAddress)->sin_port)) : std::to_string(ntohs(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6 *>(&clientAddress)->sin6_port)));
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Server<T>::Send(ConnectionPtr connection, const Message<T> &message) const
{
    if (connection->IsOpen())
        connection->Send(message);
}

template <typename T>
void Server<T>::SendAll(const Message<T> &message, ConnectionPtr ignore) const
{
    for (const ConnectionPtr &connection : mConnections)
    {
        if (connection != ignore && connection->IsOpen())
            connection->Send(message);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Server<T>::ProcessMessage()
{
    OwnedMessage<T> message(mInMessageQueue.Front());
    mInMessageQueue.DeQueue();

    OnMessage(message.GetSender(), message);
}

template <typename T>
void Server<T>::RemoveConnections()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (typename Vector<ConnectionPtr>::Iterator it = mConnections.Begin(), end = mConnections.End(); it != end; ++it)
            if (!(*it)->IsOpen())
            {
                (*it)->Close();
                OnClientDisconnect(*it);
                it = mConnections.Remove(it);
            }
    }
}


#endif  // SERVER_H
```

Everything works fine, but I have problems with synchronizing the container of Connections in the server: it is accessed by both the listening thread (which inserts new connections) and the garbage collector thread (which scans the array for dead connection to remove).

How can I address this issue? A vector is obviously the worst choice (dynamic reallocation), being inherently unsafe for concurrent access, but how can I store connections that needs to be manipulated by different threads? Please I need basic/bare-bones/not fancy solutions, since this application is for learning purposes only.

As an aside, how/where can I start learning about how to structure network code more efficiently? How can I improve the structure of my framework?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a mutex?

Comment: _Each connection runs in two threads_ - that's the root of your problems. Use non-blocking I/O. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html